# OpenCV, OpponentColorDescriptorExtractor, and Python

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

It's pretty simple to extract SURF descriptors using cv2 and Python. You just need to initialize the descriptor and apply it, using something along the lines of:

```
extractor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SURF")
```

But what about the OpponentColorDescriptorExtractor as mentioned [here, towards the bottom of the page](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_extractors.html)?

I have seen C++ code to create an Opponent Color extractor [via this blog post](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/08/25/a-simple-object-classifier-with-bag-of-words-using-opencv-2-3-w-code/), but I cannot find any Python bindings to go with it.

Does anyone know how to create an Opponent Color descriptor extractor using Python bindings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should have read the docs a little better. All you need to do is prepend opponent to the descriptor:

```
>>> d = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SURF") # normal SURF descriptor
>>> d = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("OpponentSURF") # SURF descriptor applied to each channel in the opponent color space and concatenated together
```